# Criteria based event Subscription in HyperLedger Fabric using Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Why Hyperledger Composer does not allow **criteria based event subscription** in Hyperledger Fabric.

As the subscriber receive all the events forcing the developer to implement event filtering in application logic thus impacting the efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its emitted to each peer with an event URL definition by Fabric  and hence will get a notification from each peer (ie each having eventUrl with defined event listener in the connection profile).

you could if you wish, return data from a transaction (such as one designed to return a specific business event to the client). See [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts#returning-data-from-transaction-processor-functions) for more details.